# Importing Historical S&P 500 Data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, stock, yfinance

I am trying to pull the historical stock data, e.g., open price and volume, for all of the S&P 500 stocks and then print the data. However, my code is flawed. When I run my code, I receive a message saying "AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)", and "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'." Where am I going wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
table=pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
df = table[0]
df.to_csv('S&P500-Info.csv')
df.to_csv("S&P500-Symbols.csv", columns=['Symbol'])

col_list = ["Symbol"]
df = pd.read_csv("S&P500-Symbols.csv", usecols=col_list)
stockdata = (df)

!pip install yfinance 
import yfinance as yf   

full_stock_data = yf.download(stockdata,'2010-01-01','2021-03-03') 
print(full_stock_data)
```

Comment: "My code is not working" is not a particularly clear or helpful description. Please [edit] to describe your expected output, your current output, and the difference between the two, or the full error traceback of any errors you are encountering, so that we can understand how to help

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I edited my post to include more information. However, I am very new to coding, so if there is something else that I should include, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yf.download` needs a python list not a pd.Series. Your csv-construct would work i think, but there's no need for it at all. This should work:

```
 table = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
 df = table[0]
 stockdata = df['Symbol'].to_list()
 full_stock_data = yf.download(stockdata, '2010-01-01', '2021-03-03')
 print(full_stock_data['Volume'])
```

Comment: You fixed my problem. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of tickers in a column. Now your asking yfinance to pull mutiple columns for each ticker over multiple days.

Enclosed is the output for 1 ticker symbol. Notice that the symbol is not included in the data.

[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close  
Date
2010-01-04   26.000362   26.177889   25.870815   26.129908   20.074522
2010-01-05   26.134706   26.134706   25.789249   25.918797   19.912334
2010-01-06   25.880411   26.096321   25.837231   26.062737   20.022911
2010-01-07   26.057938   26.283443   25.942785   26.278646   20.188793
2010-01-08   26.273848   26.508949   26.235464   26.412991   20.292002
...                ...         ...         ...         ...         ...
2021-02-24  120.800003  122.910004  120.660004  122.379997  122.379997
2021-02-25  121.660004  122.760002  120.769997  121.580002  121.580002
2021-02-26  122.190002  122.360001  119.660004  119.779999  119.779999
2021-03-01  120.989998  122.949997  120.610001  122.209999  122.209999
2021-03-02  122.209999  123.099998  121.190002  122.529999  122.529999

```
          Volume
```

Date
2010-01-04  10829095
2010-01-05  10562109
2010-01-06  11401417
2010-01-07  12857232
2010-01-08  12148604
...              ...
2021-02-24   4127400
2021-02-25   3468900
2021-02-26   5197500
2021-03-01   3858600
2021-03-02   4908100

[2809 rows x 6 columns]

what you can do is something like this

```
    import pandas_datareader as web
    import pandas as pd
    #get your symbols using your code - mine is stocks
    dfAdjClose = web.DataReader(stocks, "yahoo", start="2010-01-01", end="2021-01-31") 
    ["Adj Close"]
    repeat for other data then you can do code to combine by symbol
```